# How to match a numeric range out of 23:59?

Tags: python, regex

I have possible strings in the format of:

```
x:y
```

where x & y could be multiple digits. I want to match the opposite of 23:59, meaning that x must be > 23 & y must be > 59, how to write that pattern? My intention is that, if a string x:y is not like a time format, i.e. 08:23, I want to exclude it. Note that the string could be:

```
8:23 OR
08:23
```

Both refers to 8:23am. I have to match the opposite of 23:59, since my program's logic works this way. The following pattern seems to match 0<x<=23 & 0<y<=59

```
 ([0-1][1-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5][0-9]
```

How to match the opposite of this, if the above regex is correct?

Comment: ``"\d{,2}:\d{,2}"`` ?

Comment: If these are supposed to represent times, then you should use a library for handling times, and *not* assume that you have to impart that meaning yourself.

Comment: Also, trying to do math with regex is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `dateutil.parser`:

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

def is_time(str_):
    try:
        dparser.parse(str_, fuzzy=True)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

times = ["8:23", "08:23", "28:23", "23:61"]

for t in times:
    print(t, is_time(t))
```

Output:

```
8:23 True
08:23 True
28:23 False # Wrong hour
23:61 False # Wrong min
```

Answer (score 1):

Look aheads might come to the rescue here:

```
\b(?!23:59)([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\b
```

The negative lookahead at the very start of the pattern `(?!23:59)` excludes `23:59`, and the rest of the pattern allows all other hours:minutes.

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

```
(((2[4-9]|[3-9][0-9]):\d\d)|(\d\d:([6-9][0-9])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct Regex for what you want is
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]

and for the opposite of the whole thing you can do the following, negating the accepted set.

(?!([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])

?! = Negative lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

> My intention is that, if a string x:y is not like a time format, i.e.
> 08:23, I want to exclude it.

**This to me seems like you just want to attempt to match the two formats and if no match, discard it.**

**Try this:**
https://regex101.com/r/pQGNyj/1

**Expression:**

```
^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])|((?<!\d)[1]*[0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$
```

**It might be what you're after...**